# In Django ModelSerializer unable to mark a field required as false

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to make a field `investor` required as `False` in Django Restframework's ModelSerializer.

```
class WatchListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = WatchList
        fields = ['id', 'investor', 'property']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'investor' : {
                'required' : False
            }
        }
```

However, both the fields are defined as `ForeignKeys` in the model. As you can see in above implementation I am trying to override the default implementation of field `investor` using `extra_kwargs`. Unfortunately, it still asking to provide the value for `investor`.

Here is the model `Watchlist` -

```
class WatchList(BaseModel):

    investor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=False, null=True)
    property = models.ForeignKey(Properties, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=False, null=True)

    class Meta:
        
       unique_together = (('investor', 'property',))

    def __str__(self):
        
        return f'Watch List Object {self.id}:'
```

Comment: can you show your `WatchList` model?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem updated question for the same.

Comment: what if you set `blank=True`, this means that the field is *not* required in a modelform, modeladmin, modelserializer, etc.

Comment: it says unknown argument `blank` found.

Comment: I mean in the *model*, not the serializer.

Comment: Yes, that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [**`blank=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#blank), you specify whether the field is *required* in a `ModelForm`, `ModelAdmin`, `ModelSerializer` and other parts of the code that process data into a model object.

You thus can disable this with:

```
class WatchList(BaseModel):
    # …
    property = models.ForeignKey(
        Properties,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
```